# Example of functor from groups to groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory

I have to provide two examples of a functor $F:$ **Grp** $\to$ **Grp**, such that its object function is the identity, i.e. $F(G) =G$ for every group $G$. Clearly the identity functor is one, but I can't see an other one (I have been trying for quite long). Can you give me just a hint? Thank you in advance